# Python Clicker Game

Tags: python, tkinter

I have come up with some code that I am using for a clicker game, kinda like Cookie Clicker.

```
from tkinter import *
import time

master = Tk()

def uiPrint():
    info()
    print("")
    print(click)
    blankLine()

def info():
    print("Double click purchases need 50 clicks!")
    print("Auto clicker purchases need 75 clicks!")

info()

click = 0
mult = 1
dcp1 = 0

def blankLine():
    for i in range(20):
        print("")

def purchaseDoubleClicksCommand():
    global click
    global mult
    if click < 5:
        print("Not enough clicks!")
        blankLine()
    elif click >= 5:
        mult = mult*2
        click = click - 5
        print("Double Clicks Purchased!")
        blankLine()


def purchaseAutoClickerCommand():
    global click
    if click < 7:
        print("Not enough clicks!")
        blankLine()
    elif click >= 7:
        click = click - 7
        print("Auto clicker purchased!")
        while True:
            click = click + 1
            time.sleep(1)


def buttonCommand():
    global click
    global mult
    click += 1*(mult)
    uiPrint()

    if click == 100:
        print('''Achievement Unlocked: Junior Clicker!
        BONUS 100 clicks!''')
        click += 100

    elif click == 400:
        print ('''Achievement Unlocked: Little Ninja Clicks!
        BONUS 200!''')
        click += 300

    elif click == 1500:
        print ('''Achievement Unlocked: Click Ninja Master!
        QUAD CLICKS!''')
        mult = mult * 4

    elif click == 3000:
        print ('''Achievement Unlocked:  Jackie Chan Style!
        8 TIMES THE CLICKS!''')
        mult = mult * 8

mainClickButton = Button(master, text="Click!", command = buttonCommand)
mainClickButton.pack()

purchaseDoubleClickButton = Button(master, text="Purchase Double Clicks", command = purchaseDoubleClicksCommand)
purchaseDoubleClickButton.pack()

purchaseAutoClickerButton = Button(master, text="Purchase Auto Clicker", command = purchaseAutoClickerCommand)
purchaseAutoClickerButton.pack()

master.title("Clicker! v0.0.6")
master.geometry("%sx%s+%s+%s" % (200,70,512,512))
mainloop()
```

This is the code that I have so far. I am trying to add an Auto Clicker that you can buy through a button. I have found one other post that is about this, but the solution for that uses PyMouse which 1.) I can't get installed (Trust me I've tried everything) and 2.) Don't want to imitate user input.

So this is the code in question.

```
def purchaseAutoClickerCommand():
    global click
    if click < 7:
        print("Not enough clicks!")
        blankLine()
    elif click >= 7:
        click = click - 7
        print("Auto clicker purchased!")
        while True:
            click = click + 1
            time.sleep(1)
```

And the code in charge of the button

```
purchaseAutoClickerButton = Button(master, text="Purchase Auto Clicker", command = purchaseAutoClickerCommand)
purchaseAutoClickerButton.pack()
```

When I hit the button that says "Purchase Auto Clicker", not only do I not get the number of clicks to increase by one per second, but the entire app crashes.

So my main question is, how can I have the number of clicks increase by one per second by the game itself (without the user needing to keep the mouse on the "Click!" button), and how can I have the Auto Clickers stack when more than one are bought (plus I would like to not have the program crash as soon as I try to buy it).

Editing this for Scratso to see:

This is what I have changed to the code

```
click = 0
mult = 1
dcp1 = 0
autoclickers = 0

def blankLine():
    for i in range(20):
        print("")

def purchaseDoubleClicksCommand():
    global click
    global mult
    if click < 5:
        print("Not enough clicks!")
        blankLine()
    elif click >= 5:
        mult = mult*2
        click = click - 5
        print("Double Clicks Purchased!")
        blankLine()


def purchaseAutoClickerCommand():
    global click
    global autoclickers
    if click < 7:
        print("Not enough clicks!")
        blankLine()
    elif click >= 7:
        autoclickers += 1 # add an autoclicker
        click = click - 7
        print("Auto clicker purchased!")
```

And at the end of the code I have added

```
while True:
    mainClickButton = Button(master, text="Click!", command = buttonCommand)
    mainClickButton.pack()

    purchaseDoubleClickButton = Button(master, text="Purchase Double Clicks", command = purchaseDoubleClicksCommand)
    purchaseDoubleClickButton.pack()

    purchaseAutoClickerButton = Button(master, text="Purchase Auto Clicker", command = purchaseAutoClickerCommand)
    purchaseAutoClickerButton.pack()

    master.title("Clicker! v0.0.6")
    master.geometry("%sx%s+%s+%s" % (200,70,512,512))
    mainloop()

    for autoclicker in range(autoclickers):
        click += 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Why did you add an infinite loop with widget creation and a `time.sleep()` call? That's guaranteed to produce unwanted behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with using `sleep()` in a `tkinter` application is that it messes with the way the GUI is updated. Instead, call `after()` on the root `tkinter` object to tell it to execute the given command (function) after the given number of milliseconds have elapsed. This `after()` call will be placed within the function itself, so that, after calling this function normally, it will be called again one second later.

```
autoclickers=0 # start autoclickers at 0

def purchaseAutoClickerCommand():
    global click
    global autoclickers # declare global
    if click < 7:
        print("Not enough clicks!")
        blankLine()
    else:
        click -= 7 # pay for an autoclicker
        print("Auto clicker purchased!")
        autoclickers += 1 # receive an autoclicker

def autoclick():
    global master
    global click
    global autoclickers
    click += autoclickers # get clicks from autoclickers
    master.after(1000, autoclick) # do this again 1 second later

autoclick() # start benefiting from all existing autoclickers
```

Comment: Alright, I have implemented this code. The number increases 1 per second, but it doesn't update the number of clicks that I have until I hit the click button again. Any way that you know how to fix that?

Comment: The number increases, but doesn't update? Do you mean that it doesn't show you the new number until you hit the click button, but when you do so, it displays the correct number?

Comment: Yes. And I dont know how to fix it

Comment: Put a `if autoclickers: print(click)` inside `autoclick()`.

Comment: Also, I don't know if your game's autoclickers benefit from the multiplier, but if they do, you'd use `click += autoclickers*mult` instead of just `click += autoclickers`.

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend for just the clicking is just using a module like pyautogui or something which can type keys and click on its own, unless you were asking for like a autoclicker but you can click on the side

EDIT

you could use a while loop which adds 1 per second

Answer (score 0):

well, I noticed that using time will just lag everything. Try using timers or make it add .00001 clicks so it will make it kinda like a timer.

Answer (score -4):

I downloaded an autoclicker my self and after 5 seconds of holding my mouse over the click button and ten over the double button i achieved this amount of clicks. (copy, paste)

755556783768937868934768457868378674578897653689974322127907543098763683978387683767937784870388737657475555678376893786893476845786837867457889765368997432212790754309876368397838768376793778487038873765747555567837689378689347684578683786745788976536899743221279075430987636839783876837679377848703887376574755556783768937868934768457868378674578897653689974322127907543098763688934768457868378674578897653689974322127907543098763683978387683767937784870388737657475555678376893786893476445533384578683786745788976536899743221279075430987636839783876837679377848703887376574755556783768937868934224457684578683786745788976536899743221279075430987636839783876837679377848703887376574755556783768937868934768457868378674578897653689974322127907543098763683978387683767937784870388737657475555678376893786893476845786837867457889765368997432212790754309876366666666664344667645544448397838768376793778487038873765747555567837689378689347684578683786745788976536899743221279075430987636839783876837679377848703887333765747555567837689378689347684578683786745788976536899743221279075430987636839783876837679377848703887376574755556783768937868934768457868378674578897653689974322127907543098783978383333368376793778487038873765747555567837689378689347684578683786745788976536899743221279075430987636839783876837679377848703887376574755556783768937868934768457868378674578897653689974322127907543098763683978387683767937784870388737657475555678376893786893476845786837867457889765666536899743221279075430987636839783876837679377848703887376574755556783768937868934768457868378674578897653689974322127907543098763683978387683767937784870388737657475555678376893786893476845786837867457889765368997432212790754309876368397838768376793778487038873765747555567837689378689347684578683786745788976536899743221279075430987636839783876837679377848703887376574755556783768937868934768457868378674578897653689974322127907543098763683978387683767937784870388737657475555678376893786893476845786837867457889765368997432212790754309876368397838768376793778487038873765747555567837689378689347684578683786745788976536899743221279075430987636839783876837679377848703887376574